# Laravel websockets connection failed

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I've got a Laravel 8 API project along with a Nuxt JS front-end that uses Laravel Echo. I'm installed the Laravel Websockets server and have everything working just fine with the Pusher replacement config:

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'http'
    ],
],
```

It's also worth noting here that I've also tried:

```
'options' => [
    ...
    'port' => 6001,
    'scheme' => 'https'
],
```

and...

```
'options' => [
    ...
    'port' => 443,
    'scheme' => 'https'
],
```

However, when I deploy to my CentOS 8 server and start the websockets server with `php artisan websockets:serve` *(I'm in debug mode)* and I try to connect, I'm getting a connection failed error. I'm using the default port of `6001` and default host of `0.0.0.0`, the error I get from my front-end is:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1/app/local?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false' failed:

My front-end is for example: https://example-gui.example.com/ whilst my running API is on https://example-api.example.com/, both on the same server, and the same server as the running websockets server.

I'm using Cloudflare for HTTPs, and I'm not sure whether I need to change anything with the host?

I originally had the connection like this:

> 'wss://127.0.0.1/app/local?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false', when I run `netstat -tulnp` I do indeed see that port `6001` is in there.

What am I missing to connect in production?

I'm stuck in knowing how to get it to connect!

Comment: Set up your frontend Laravel Echo to use the proper domain: `https://example-api.example.com` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I've tried with the domain, and it continues to hang

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your front end is still trying to connect to the localhost version of the websocket server.

[image]

Try replacing that with your example-api URL.

Comment: I've tried setting it up with the domain, and I get the same result with the exception that it's the domain rather than the localhost variant, so I don't see this being the issue in this case